# How to alter printed text

Tags: string, string-formatting

In plenty of system commands and programs, especially those which display some sort of progress bar or updated information, characters which have already been printed, are altered.

I am wondering how this would be done in any programming language, as I can only achieve a similar effect by running a `clear` system command and printing the new characters in place of the old ones to give the illusion of the characters being 'replaced', which needless to say is a far less 'elegant' method.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the system you are running, but for the Linux terminal it is possible for a program to print special characters that controls the terminal. E.g. printing the byte `0x08` performs the backspace action.

Many of these console codes are listed in the `console_codes(4)` man page.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html